# Google Map div, hidden by a container div

Tags: google-maps

I have a div which contains a #map div which I use to display a Google map.

The problem I'm having is that, I'm unable to interact with the map in any way, because it's being 'hidden' by the div encapsulating it.

How do I avoid this?

```
<div id="container">

    <!-- This div is 'on top' of the map, therefore I 
        cannot access it/invoke click events on it. -->

    <div id="map">
        <!-- This is where the map is loaded -->
    </div>

    <div id="description">

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: how can `container` be on top of the `map` while containing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you place a `position:relative` in the css on the map div and then bring the `z-index` of that div to any number higher than the `z-index` of the container, you should be able to interact with the map.

If you are generating the map while the div is hidden, trigger the resize event for the map using `google.maps.event.trigger(map,"resize")` where `map` is the JS variable containing the Google map object.